flutter MenuItemButton: how to limit its expansion and remove left margin?
  Column(children: [
    Row(children: [
      SizedBox(width: 200,
        child: Text('Name')),
      Flexible(
        child: Text('John')),
      ),
    ],

    Row(children: [
      SizedBox(width: 200,
        child: Text('Order Id')),
      Flexible(
        child: MenuItemButton(
          child: Text('123456')),
      ),
    ],
  ]);

The MenuItemButton expands to occupy all the available space in the Row. It has left padding/margin so that it does not align with the other values in the same column.
 Name     | John
-----------------------------
 Order Id |   123456        |

How to let the MenuItemButton have a width to fit its child? How to remove its left padding to align with "John" ?
Tried:
MenuItemButton(
  style: const ButtonStyle(
      tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      minimumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(0, 0))),
  child: Text('123456'))


The left padding is coming from TextButtonStyle's default padding which can be manipulate by using style
 MenuItemButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
      EdgeInsets.all(0),
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('123456'),

